# mysql how to check time interval based on the last time the user visited the place?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a client table that displays if thats the first time the client has visited the place and the client individual id, the point is i need to know if a user took longer than 6(360 minutes) hours to return.

Check the code to see how far i managed to reach by myself:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE Client (
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    user_id VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    first_time_buying VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    visit_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO Client
    (user_name, user_id, first_time_buying, visit_date)
VALUES
    ('Fred', '1','yes' ,'2020-02-15 23:59:59'),
    ('Fernanda','2', 'yes', '2020-02-17 12:35:00'),
    ('Fred','1', 'no', '2020-02-21 15:59:09'),
    ('Fernanda','2', 'no','2020-03-01 11:06:39'),
    ('Fred','1', 'no', '2020-02-21 16:36:39)

;
```

the select i created:

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
              (SELECT t1.visit_date
              from Client t1 inner join(select user_name, max(Id) as maxID from Client
                                       group by user_name) t2 on t1.user_name = t2.user_name
              and t1.Id = t2.maxID
              where t1.user_id = '2'),
              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS Difference
```

i also need to deduct the current timestamp with the last time the user entered the place and if its less than 360 minutes return null else return true or the minutes amount.

For example:

if the last time he/she visited the shop was up to 6h ago i was expecting to get null or false, if its more than that i was expecting to get the value or true.

ps: it must be compared with the current timestamp value.

i may provide more info only if necessary.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the fiddle here, so we don't have to navigate away from this page

Comment: And provide desired result for same

Comment: Agree with @Strawberry that what you want the results to be is unclear

Comment: @Kevin I find your stance contradictory and confusing

Comment: i just want to deduct the current timestamp with the last time the client came to the shop and finds out if it has more than 6h since he last came in. I need to improve my english!

Comment: @Strawberry ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns correct results but it is overcomplicated.
You can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    MINUTE,
    (
      SELECT MAX(visit_date)
      FROM Client 
      WHERE user_id = '2'
    ),   
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  ) AS Difference;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/miFiRsFFjUBZssEQwx4qh6/1).
Or check [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/miFiRsFFjUBZssEQwx4qh6/3).

Comment: your solution is way simplier! Thank you!

Comment: ur answer helped me to see many mistakes ive made during creating the query meanwhile @Kevin answer gave me what i needed to check the time intervals.

Comment: My answer answered the requirement as you posted it in the question. You did not ask for a solution that would include all the users. Your code was about one specific user. Right?

Comment: ive just checked ur second link and tbh i dont know what to do, both answers are correct!

Comment: Are they both correct for the requirement as you posted it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209540/discussion-between-jacob-d-davis-and-forpas).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, max(c1.visit_date), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 360 then 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END as MoreThanSixHours
from client c1
group by c1.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks thats all i needed iam still learning SQL, tbh i wasnt expecting such an easy solution, gladly theres one!

Comment: Both answer meet the requirements i  dont know what to do :S